# Autoscroll Doesn't work in Child UserControl

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, user-controls, scrollbars

I have a UserControl `Parent` that contains `Child` controls. I would like my `Parent` control to Autoscroll when it is too small for its `Child`. To get Autoscroll, I've set AutoScroll to True in my `Parent`, and ensured that the `Child` is large enough that I can resize the `Parent` to be smaller than it. My `Parent` is contained inside a `Form` and is anchored to all four edges. The problem is that I cannot seem to get the scrollbars to appear during runtime.

I cannot display a control without a form, of course, unless it's in Designer. In Visual Studio 2008 Designer, the `Parent` Autoscrolls perfectly: I can resize the control, and whenever its `Child` is partially hidden by the edge of `Parent`, the scrollbars appear. However, when viewing the control in either the `Form`'s designer or during runtime, the scrollbars do not appear, no matter how I resize the `Parent`.

This seems like a bug, but feels more like I'm missing something obvious. Something about being a child of the `Form` seems to be inhibiting the AutoScroll.

Comment: you have to  **de-Anchor (bottom and right) of child** . only anchor top and left, or else scrollbars won't be visible

Answer (score 2):

Try setting dock=none.  There appears to be an issue with docking and scroll bars.  In my own tests with AutoScroll=true: if Dock=Fill then no scrollbars, if Dock=Top then vertical scrollbar, if Dock=Left then horizontal scrollbar, if Dock=None then both scrollbars.

In the end I set Dock=None for my user controls and scrollbars appeared as expected.

Comment: But what if you still need the docked behavior? For the `Child` to fill the area alloted for it in the `Parent`?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried placing a Panel docked inside your parent control with your user control inside the Panel?

Comment: Thanks for contributing. I just added a panel between the `Parent` and `Child` controls. I then set the AutoScroll of the `Parent` to false, and of the panel to true. The AutoScroll still worked while I was designing the `Parent`, but still fails when designing the `Form` or during runtime.

Comment: I created a simple example form which contains a dock=fill panel with AutoScroll=true. Inside the panel I put a listbox with 15 items. When I resize the form the panel shows a scrollbar if the the list is too long to display completely. The code is below. If yours isn't working maybe you have the internal control docked? It needs to grow beyond the bounds of the panel.

Comment: this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.listBox1);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(284, 265);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue.... with my child controls to be created dynamically and then to enable the parent for autoscroll option.

The issue was because i had docked the child panel to left. When we dont dock then parent was working successfully...